# Is it possible to display preferences inside the app with settings.bundle?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

Is it possible to display preferences **inside the app** using `Settings.bundle`? If not, is there a similar approach to Settings.bundle for showing preferences inside the app?

The reason why I want to use Settings.bundle is because it uses a simple .plist file with a tiny bit of `UserDefaults` code which makes it possible to create userpreferences.

Currently I have inside app preferences with lots of code in my custom wrapper class around `UserDefaults` - I'd rather refactor this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in to iOS or UIKit that does this.

You'll have to roll your own settings view, or use a 3rd-Party library. For example, check out [InAppSettingsKit](https://github.com/futuretap/InAppSettingsKit). This library mimics the behaviour of the Settings app in a View Controller that you can display in your app, using the regular Settings.bundle. I've used it successfully in a bunch of apps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18497122)

Comment: Updated my answer.